# Создание 100% кроссплатформенной библиотеки

Tags: c#, uwp

Случилось несчастье - мне необходимо написать приложение на UWP. Разумеется, проектирую все по модели MVC. Тестировать и разрабатывать модели мне намного удобнее в консольном приложении, и так часто случается, что те классы, которые прекрасно работали для консольного app не находят определения классов в приложении UWP и наоборот. Так как писать максимально кроссплатформенно?

Я понимаю, например, класс для работы с камерой может не работать в консольном приложении, но чтобы не работали классы шифрования или сериализации...тут уж прошу простить меня - в ад разработчиков этого всего!

У меня есть библиотека, но при ее подключении мне вылетает ошибка:

[image: 1]

Если же я создаю переносимую библиотеку и указываю целевую платформу UWP, то он не знает о существовании таких классов как: BinaryFormatter, Aes, AesCryptoServiceProvider, CryptoStream, Serializable. Это, в принципе, логично, потому что их не удосужились добавить в UWP! Кроме как писать свои алгоритмы реализации, можно как-то перенести эти классы? Существует ли хоть какая-то кроссплатформенность???

Answer (score 1):

Бинарная сериализация существенно зависима от рефлексии и динамической генерации кода, поэтому она, к сожалению, недоступна в ограниченных подмножествах .NET (UWP/Silverlight/.NET Core). Возможно, имеет смысл перейти на XML-сериализацию или `DataContractSerializer`.

А с криптографией всё не так плохо! Просто она «переехала» в [другой namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.aspx). Вам нужно использовать [`SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.openalgorithm.aspx) с одним из AES-параметров, полный список [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetricalgorithmnames.aspx).

---

Возможно, эта часть кода не будет легко переносима на десктоп. Для этого по идее в Universal App можно выделить общую и платформозависимую части.

Comment: Мне нужно производить операцию object to byte [] и наоборот. 
С криптографией не все так плохо...все ужасно! Зачем? Зачем этот переезд? И почему нет поддержки старой версии (не знаю просто как сказать по другому)?

Comment: @SanychGoilo: `object to byte[]` — это и есть сериализация. И вам по идее должно быть всё равно, какая именно.

Comment: @SanychGoilo: Почему криптография переехала, я лично не знаю. Может быть потому, что используется системная имплементация, а не таскается свой велосипед. В любом случае, смотрите на проблему не эмоционально, а прагматически: у вас **есть** криптография на платформе, так что никакой катастрофы нету. А то, что там другой namespace и немного другой синтаксис — ну так вы ж программист, справитесь.

Comment: Мне важно получит byte [].
Время потрачено зря, вот и все эмоции. До последнего не верю, что это нельзя как-то решить.

Comment: @SanychGoilo: Ну а чем вам XML-сериализация не угодила? Или `DataContractSerializer`? Они точно так же дадут вам массив байт на выходе.

Comment: А чем мне класс ECDiffieHellmanCng заменить?

Comment: @SanychGoilo: Ну поищите в https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.aspx, там наверняка есть.

Comment: @SanychGoilo: Хм, хотя может быть его там нет: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4581

Comment: @SanychGoilo: [X25519](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.ecccurvenames.curve25519.aspx) — это случайно не Diffie-Hellman?

Comment: Вот именно что нету. Да, это  Diffie-Hellman.

Comment: @SanychGoilo: Вот [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/655d5590-45bf-4b9d-a2e7-b09833cea059/uwp-argumentexception-when-encrypting-data-using-an-ecc-cryptographickey?forum=wpdevelop) есть код `AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.EcdsaSha512).CreateKeyPairWithCurveName(EccCurveNames.NistP521);` — а если поменять кривую на X25519?

Comment: Даже по названию функции видно (asymenric) видно что это не то. Д-Х симметричный алгоритм. Там показано как шифровать с помощью aes.

Comment: По сути, тот класс просто организовывал все математические действия  , генерировал ключи.